# I am using Android Studio on Mac, and one of the projects (that others can access and work on) is giving me this error message

Tags: android, macos

Error:Could not read cache value from '/Users/aishwaryagagadam/.gradle/daemon/2.8/registry.bin'.

And my folder aishwaryagagadam has no .gradle folder, so the path ends there

Comment: remove .gradle/daemon/2.8/registry.bin from project path.

Comment: What do you mean by there is no .gradle folder? Have you tried to rebuild the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the `.gradle` directory as `trash -rf /Users/aishwaryagagadam/.gradle` and rebuild the project. It should fix the error.